# Symfony3/Doctrine — effectivly build data tree without lazy loading

Tags: tree, doctrine, symfony, nested-sets

I have a Model which represents a Tree, which looks like this:

```
class Category
{

  //the definition of the $id and $parent_id is abbreviated

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
   */
  private $children;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $parent = null;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
  }

  public function getChildren()
  {
    return $this->children;
  }

  //Getter and Setters following

}
```

To retrieve the resulting tree I have created a simple `\RecursiveIterator` which works **BUT** creates a single Database Request each time any data of a category is requested. I searched the web and came over [this](http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/hierarchical-data.html) article which describes the creating of hierarchical data in doctrine.

In case this way is not possible in Symfony, it would be possible to load all entries from the database in a single query and construct all objects once and than build the tree.

So my question is: How can I use Doctrine Hierarchical Data in Symfony? If not possible, how can I load all rows from the database in one single query?

Thanks in Ahead!

Comment: You can load all **needed** rows in one single query if you know **beforehand** where to start the tree and how many levels you require. Would you know that beforehand ?

Comment: Yes, I know that, there is only one root in that table. How can I load all at once?

Answer (score 0):

**In the `Category` entity**:

Make the `children` property `EXTRA_LAZY` in case you do access them.  This will stop the full load trigger on certain methods, specifically `count`, just in case.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Add a method `hasChildren` to return `true` if there are any children.  If you simply did `count($this->children)` it would only trigger a `count` query because of `EXTRA_LAZY`, which is still better than a full load.

But there is another way. At runtime, `children` is an instance of  `PersistentCollection` and it has a method `getSnapshot` which returns the last snapshot of the elements in the collection.  In other words, only whats loaded and will not even issue a `count` query. This may seem a little *hack-ish* but it works.

```
class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    private $children;

    // ...

    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return count($this->children->getSnapshot()) > 0;
    }
}
```

Now to load all the needed entities/rows create a method `findByRootId` in 
`CategoryRepository`.  This would still work even if you set `$level` to something bigger than the actual levels in the database.

Performance is affected by each added level due to the additional joins but Unless your *tree* contains thousands of elements, it works pretty well overall.

```
public function findByRootId($id, $level = 10)
{
    $children = '';
    $joins = '';

    for ($j = 0, $i = 1; $i <= $level; $i++, $j++) {
        $children .= ", c{$i}";
        $joins .= "LEFT JOIN c{$j}.children c{$i} ";
    }

    // Change `YourBundleName` with you actual namespace/bundle name
    $query = "SELECT c0 {$children}
              FROM YourBundleName:Category c0
              {$joins}
              WHERE c0.id = :rootId";

    return $this
            ->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($query)
            ->setParameter('rootId', $id)
            ->getSingleResult();
}
```

And finally when rendering, if you try to access a child that's not loaded doctrine will trigger a full load event. Use the `hasChildren` method to see if a child is *loaded*.

**Note**: A child may exist and just not loaded due to the specified `level`.

```
{% macro tree(parent) %}
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ parent.name }}
            {% if parent.hasChildren %}
                {% for child in parent.children %}
                    {{ _self.tree(child) }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as builder %}

{% block body %}
    {{ builder.tree(parent) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps, its not pretty but it works.